# PHP Array filter and create new array based on the result of filtered array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have a variable `$offices['results']`  when var dumped will output like this:

```
array() {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#16067 (24) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["blog_id"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["office_name"]=>
    string(0) "Japan"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#16064 (24) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["blog_id"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["office_name"]=>
    string(0) "USA"
  }
[2]=>
  object(stdClass)#16064 (24) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["blog_id"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["office_name"]=>
    string(0) "USA"

  }
}
```

I only want to create a new array variable where the `blog_id` is `10` and `12`, which will return:

```
array() {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#16067 (24) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["blog_id"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["office_name"]=>
    string(0) "Japan"
  }   
[1]=>
  object(stdClass)#16064 (24) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["blog_id"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["office_name"]=>
    string(0) "USA"

  }
}
```

I tried array_filter but I cant make it work.

```
$array = $offices['results'];

$like = '11','12';

$result = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($like) {
    if (stripos($item['blog_id'], $like) !== false) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
var_dump($result);
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: How did you try array_filter?

Comment: @shingo, sorry I forgot to input, I just edited my question

Comment: Really? It would just be `return $value->blog_id == 10 || $value->blog_id == 12`

Comment: What data type is this? `$like = '11','12';`

Comment: @Andreas yes like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through this `array` and check if the `blog_id` exists or not

but first, let's assign an `array` with your `blog_id` you want

```
$blogs = [10, 12];
```

after that, you can start iterate through your data

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $blog){
  if(in_array($blog->blog_id, $blogs)){
     $result[] = $blog;
  }
}
```

Comment: the `$data` is the `$offices['results'] `, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but how about this way with `array_filter()`?

```
$filterBy = [10,12];
$array = $offices['results'];
$newArray = array_filter($array, function ($var) use ($filterBy) {
    return in_array($var->blog_id,$filterBy);
});
```

Comment: Im sorry Im confused, but how did you called the `$offices['results']` in your code? because  what I know is you will need to call the first array `$offices['results'];`? like in my code above I called it first `$array = $offices['results']`

Comment: @ICGDEVS exactly, Yes I just added the demo code so you can fix easily :)